# PHPExcel - read comment from a cell?

Tags: comments, phpexcel

Sorry, for my bad english.

I have written the following code.

```
    foreach ($sheetData as $theData)
    if ($theData['A'] != "ID")
    {
        $id          = $theData['A'];
        $vorname     = $theData['B'];
        $nachname    = $theData['C'];
        $bew_foto    = $theData['D'];
        $emailadr    = $theData['E'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO datensatz (
                     id,
                     vorname,
                     nachname,
                     emailadr)
                 VALUES (
                     $id,
                     '$vorname',
                     '$nachname',
                     '$emailadr')";
        $ergebnis = $mysqli->query($sql);
        echo "Datensatz erfolgreich eingetragen!<br>";{     
    }
}
```

How can I make it, that I can read a comment in (to example) column B and write it in a database or give it out with an echo? I will read the comments in all rows 'nachname' (C). How can I make this?

Comment: Comments are against cells, not against columns

Answer (score 1):

To read a comment in cell A2, it's as easy as

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getComment('A2')
    ->getText();
```